# Should single character edits be allowed?

Tags: discussion, editing

I know short edits are discouraged, and rightly so, but I don't think they should be completely disallowed. Sometimes a single character can make a large difference.  For example,

> "Frodo was Sam's employee"

is wrong and in a discussion about their relationship, the edit to fix it to be "employe**r**" is relevant and not, in my mind, a "bad" edit.

Comment: Yes, I've often wondered about that.

Answer (score 6):

It's really rare that a single-character change is the only thing that can be improved in a post. Look for other possible improvements: fix other spelling errors, add links for references, etc. If all else fails, leave a comment.

The topic has come up multiple times on the [main meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-edits). The answer is always no, the limit won't change: [Should tiny edits be accepted or rejected in review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82865/should-tiny-edits-be-accepted-or-rejected-in-review) — [Remove trivial edit restriction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82893/remove-trivial-edit-restriction) — [We're discouraged from fixing typos and misspellings on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/were-discouraged-from-fixing-typos-and-misspellings-on-se-sites) — [How to overcome “Edits must be at least 6 characters”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters) — [pure code formatting, to enhance a question, is impossible (without 2k rep)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87200/pure-code-formatting-to-enhance-a-question-is-impossible-without-2k-rep) — (and many more).

Comment: Oh look, [a one-character edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/21062/revisions)...  Are you sure there's a limit still in place?

Comment: @Izkata The limitation applies only to suggested edits, not to unsupervised edits by users with 2000 rep.

Comment: @Izkata that also is a one character edit the system sees as deleting 6 characters and adding 5. 11 character change by how it shows the diff.

Answer (score 5):

This is a restriction on users with less than [2000](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) rep. This shows a serious  dedication of time an effort, and is meant to stop people with very few reputation points make too many small edits.